# How to reindex array with negative integer key value, so that items 0,1,2,3,-1 sort to -1,0,1,2,3, and then renumbered to 0,1,2,3,4?

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have this:

```
$arr = [];
$arr[0] = 'second';
$arr[-1] = 'first';
```

How do I change that to `$arr[0 => 'first', 1 => 'second']`

This is the best I've come up with:

```
$new = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $new[$key + 1] = $value;
}

ksort($new);
```

But as with everything with arrays in php, I wonder if there's actually a trivial built in function I could be using?

Comment: Do you want to sort negative numbers or reindex to positive key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the array with ksort, then apply [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to it. It will reindex the keys starting with 0:

```
$arr = [];
$arr[0] = 'second';
$arr[-1] = 'first';

ksort($arr);
$result = array_values($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping for a one-liner, but a two-liner is the next best thing 

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help but wonder if your goal is simply to insert a value at the beginning of an array, maybe you are looking for `array_unshift()`?

> `array_unshift()` prepends passed elements to the front of the array. Note that the list of elements is prepended as a whole, so that the prepended elements stay in the same order. All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero while literal keys won't be changed.
>
> --https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

So instead of

```php
$arr[-1] = 'first';
```

... and then sorting, you can instead do this

```php
array_unshift($arr, 'first');
```

This inserts `'first'` at index `0` and moves every existing, numerically indexed, item in the array up one.

Comment: I am aware of `array_unshift` and would normally use that, but the use case here is "complicated" (i.e. messy) and for some reason I felt I couldn't use it in this scenario, but I may have pulled the wool over my own eyes, maybe I could, not actually tried it.  KIS,S...

Answer (score 0):

To reindex an array with negative integer key values, you can follow these steps to sort the keys and renumber them:

1. Get the array's keys using the `array_keys` function.
2. Sort the keys using the `sort` function or `asort` function if you want to preserve the corresponding values.
3. Use the `array_combine` function to combine the sorted keys with the array values, creating a new associative array.
4. Use the `array_values` function to reindex the array with numeric keys starting from 0.

Here's an example code snippet in PHP:

```php
$array = [-1 => 'A', 0 => 'B', 1 => 'C', 2 => 'D', 3 => 'E'];

// Step 1: Get the array's keys
$keys = array_keys($array);

// Step 2: Sort the keys
sort($keys);

// Step 3: Combine the sorted keys with the array values
$newArray = array_combine($keys, array_values($array));

// Step 4: Reindex the array with numeric keys starting from 0
$newArray = array_values($newArray);

print_r($newArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => -1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
)
```

After following these steps, the array will be reindexed with the negative integer keys sorted first, followed by the positive integer keys, and then renumbered with numeric keys starting from 0.